# In C program, how do I check if the input string is a specific name or not?

Tags: c, arrays, string

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){

char name[20];

scanf(" %s", name);

if (name == 'James'){

    printf("Welcome James");
}else{

    printf("You are not James");
}

}
```

Hope you got my idea. I know this doesn't work. But is there any way to do something like this?

Comment: Yes, `!strcmp(name,"James")`.

Comment: Better hope their name isn't "Alessandro de Alexandria" or you're going to blow that dinky character buffer.

Comment: @tadman Or also something like `Ajay Brahmakshatriya` ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
if (strcmp(name, "James") == 0)
```

instead of

```
if (name == 'James')
```

Man page of [strcmp](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strcmp):

Return Value

> The `strcmp()` and `strncmp()` functions return an integer less than,
>   equal to, or greater than zero if s1 (or the first n bytes thereof) is
>   found, respectively, to be less than, to match, or be greater than s2.

Comment: It's worth noting that `==` compares string pointers, not strings, so it compiles but is generally not what people want.

Answer (score 2):

try: strcmp()

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){

char name[20];

scanf(" %s", name);

if (strcmp(name,"James")){

    printf("Welcome James");
}else{

    printf("You are not James");
}

}
```

Ref : [How do I properly compare strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8004237/how-do-i-properly-compare-strings)

Comment: `strcmp(name,'James')` you sure about that?

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya Opps, sorry syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

In C you have to use cmp string function:

```
strcmp(const char* s1, const char* s2);
```

Return values of function:

```
return value == 0 - s1 is equals s2
return value > 0 - s1 is longer than s2
return value < 0- s1 is smaller than s2
```

It is beacuse if you write:

```
char name_buff[20];
if (name_buff == "James")
{
...
```

It doesn't mean comparsion of strings but of address in memory.
So you have to use strcmp().